# Gulp vinyl ftp - how to use clean function?

Tags: node.js, ftp, gulp, vinyl, vinyl-ftp

The `vinyl-ftp` package has a function [`clean()`](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp#connclean-globs-local-options-) but I'm not sure how to use it right. I need to:

1. get all files from my `build` folder
2. put them into the target folder on my ftp server
3. clean files if they're not available locally

I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('deploy', () => {
  let conn = ftp.create({host:host,user:user,password: password});
  return gulp.src('build/**', {base: './build/', buffer: false })
      .pipe(conn.newer('/path/on/my/server/')) // only upload newer files
      .pipe(conn.dest('/path/on/my/server/'))
      .pipe(conn.clean('build/**', './build/'));
});
```

1) and 2) is OK, but the `clean()` function does nothing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `vinyl-ftp` docs [have this to say](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp#connclean-globs-local-options-):

> **conn.clean( globs, local[, options] )**
>
> Globs remote files, tests if they are locally available at `<local>/<remote.relative>` and removes them if not.

Note that `globs` expects a path for the **remote** files on your FTP server. Since your remote files are located in `/path/on/my/server/` you have to specify that path as your glob:

```
  .pipe(conn.clean('/path/on/my/server/**', './build/'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Since I got a lot of struggle with this, here a working peace of code. It removes all files from the server that dont exist locally except the `usage` folder:

```
var connection = ftp.create({ ... });

connection.clean([
    '/*.*',
    '/!(usage)*',
    '/de/**',
    '/en/**',
    '/images/**',
    '/fonts/**',
    '/json/**',
    '/sounds/**'
], './dist', { base: '/' });
```

My files are locally on the `./dist` folder and remote directly in the root directory (`/`) (of the used ftp user).